# Difference between pathlib.Path().resolve() and pathlib.Path().parent

Tags: python, path, pathlib

I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding the difference between `pathlib.Path().resolve()` and `pathlib.Path().parent`.

If I want to be able to get the directory of the current script, do these serve the same purpose?

And are both of these location-agnostic, i.e. if I were to move the files to a different location, would my script still run?

Comment: i am not sure why this question go a downvote ?  (although it could have had some code or example: how to ask a good question:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
)

Answer (score 2):

The method `pathlib.Path().resolve()` will return an absolute path. If the path is already absolute the method will have no effect.

For example assuming you are in the working directory `/home/python` and run the following

```py
In: pathlib.Path().resolve()
Out: "/home/python"

In: pathlib.Path(".").resolve()
Out: "/home/python"

In: pathlib.Path("foo/bar.txt").resolve()
Out: "/home/python/foo/bar.txt"

In: pathlib.Path("/home/python").resolve()
Out: "/home/python"
```

To explain the example above, if you instantiate a path class `pathlib.Path()` without any arguments it will use `.` as default value, which refers to the [current working directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory#:%7E:text=In%20computing%2C%20the%20working%20directory,function%2C%20or%20just%20current%20directory.). So the first two examples both resolve to `/home/python`.

`foo/bar.txt` is a relative path. If your working directory is `/home/python` it will resolve to the absolute path `/home/python/foo/bar.txt`. If you are in the working directory `/root` it will resolve to `/root/foo/bar.txt`.

---

`pathlib.Path().parent` is another path object representing the parent of the path given.

```py
# In working directory /root
In: pathlib.Path("/home/python").parent
Out: PosixPath("/home")

In: pathlib.Path("/home/python").parent.resolve()
Out: "/home"

# In working directory /home/python
In: pathlib.Path("foo").parent
Out: PosixPath(".")

In: pathlib.Path("foo").parent.resolve()
Out: "/home/python"
```

---

Yes your script will still run in other directories if you watch out for certain things.

```py
# /home/python/foo.py

print(pathlib.Path().resolve())
```

Running this script from the directory `/home/python` will result in a path like this `/home/python`.

If you run the script from `/home` like this `python/foo.py` it will result in a path like this `/home`

If you watch out for potholes like this you should be fine to run your script from any directory. Doing mistakes here usually results in file not found errors.